# Scrolling the view to particular point when view is loaded?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a question which I couldn't achieve, please help guys. Below is my issue,

I have a database were I am storing the dates,name,time and due dates based on the date given by the user (Calculating the due dates like 10 days due,6weeks due,10 weeks due and so on till 10 years). Now my task is that when a user selects a date from the table view (Multiple dates will be displayed in the table view) I will select the data from the sqlite DB based on selected date in tableview and display the data in next view.

The next view I have a scrollview in the view in which I am displaying the data in the labels, now I have to point the scroll view based on the due date (e.g. the user date is 20-aug-2011 and the current date is 29-jan-2012 so the due date will be 6months, so I have to scroll the view and point to 6 months instead to 10 days due.)

I hope you guys understand my issue and help me, please revert if any question else post me the generic answer or hint how to proceed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setContentOffset:animated:` method of UIScrollView to scroll to a certain point.

Comment: how does these property works for my issue can u please elaborate it?

Comment: You should place the content in a `UIScrollView`. Then you have to set it's `contentSize` and after that use the `contentOffset` property like explained above.